# How to resole server side rendering issue in nextjs 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

Currently using nextJs ver:14. In the above piece of code, I'm trying to get pre-rendered values inside my Home component, but unable to get any values inside (nextflixOriginals). Till nextJs 12, this could easily be done using getServerSideProps, but it is not supported from version 13. This is my Home component, and I'm using app Router based project.

```js
import Header from './components/header/page';
import Banner from './components/banner/page';
import requests from '@/utils/requests';
import { Movie } from '@/typings';
import { NextPage } from 'next';

interface Props {
  netflixOriginals: Movie[]
  trendingNow: Movie[]
  topRated: Movie[]
  actionMovies: Movie[]
  comedyMovies: Movie[]
  horrorMovies: Movie[]
  romanceMovies: Movie[]
  documentaries: Movie[]
}

export const getMovies = async () => {
  const [
    netflixOriginals,
    trendingNow,
    topRated,
    actionMovies,
    comedyMovies,
    horrorMovies,
    romanceMovies,
    documentaries,
  ] = await Promise.all([
    fetch(requests.fetchNetflixOriginals,{cache:"no-store"}).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchTrending,{cache:"no-store"}).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchTopRated,{cache:"no-store"}).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchActionMovies,{cache:"no-store"}).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchComedyMovies,{cache:"no-store"}).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchHorrorMovies,{cache:"no-store"}).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchRomanceMovies,{cache:"no-store"}).then((res) => res.json()),
    fetch(requests.fetchDocumentaries,{cache:"no-store"}).then((res) => res.json()),
  ])
  return{
    props: {
      netflixOriginals: netflixOriginals.results,
      trendingNow: trendingNow.results,
      topRated: topRated.results,
      actionMovies: actionMovies.results,
      comedyMovies: comedyMovies.results,
      horrorMovies: horrorMovies.results,
      romanceMovies: romanceMovies.results,
      documentaries: documentaries.results
    },
  }
}

const data = async() =>{
  return await getMovies();
}
data().then((result) => {
  console.log("--->>",  result);
});

  const Home: NextPage<Props> = ({
    netflixOriginals,
  }: Props) => {
    console.log("value -->>",netflixOriginals);

  return (
    <div className="relative h-screen bg-gradient-to-b from-gray-900/10
    to-[#010511] lg:h-[140vh]">
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Banner netflixOriginals={netflixOriginals} />
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Home;
```